# Can I redirect a spell to another type of target in MTG?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

M12 features the card [Redirect](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRedirect%5d), which allows you to choose new targets for a spell. Innistrad introduced the card [Into the Maw of Hell](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bInto%20the%20Maw%20of%20Hell%5d), which deals 13 damage to target creature.

Can I redirect the damage from Into the Maw of Hell to target player with the spell Redirect or must the type of target (in this case creature) stay the same?

Comment: If you like Redirect, try Spellskite. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't redirect Into The Maw of Hell to a player.

Redirect allows you to choose new legal targets for a spell.  As such, you must choose one valid target land and one valid target creature for Into The Maw of Hell to (newly) target.  If (for instance) there is only one creature in play - yours - you could Redirect Into The Maw of Hell such that it destroyed a different land, but you would still have to keep it targeting your creature, because there are no other available legal choices.

The relevant section of the Comprehensive Rules (and the most relevant paragraph highlighted by me):

> 114.6. Some effects allow a player to change the target(s) of a spell or ability, and other effects allow a player to choose new targets for
>   a spell or ability.
>
> 114.6a If an effect allows a player to "change the target(s)" of a spell or ability, each target can be changed only to another legal
>   target. If a target can't be changed to another legal target, the
>   original target is unchanged, even if the original target is itself
>   illegal by then. If all the targets aren't changed to other legal
>   targets, none of them are changed.
>
> 114.6b If an effect allows a player to "change a target" of a spell or ability, the process described in rule 114.6a is followed, except that
>   only one of those targets may be changed (rather than all of them or
>   none of them).
>
> 114.6c If an effect allows a player to "change any targets" of a spell or ability, the process described in rule 114.6a is followed, except
>   that any number of those targets may be changed (rather than all of
>   them or none of them).
>
> **114.6d If an effect allows a player to "choose new targets" for a spell or ability, the player may leave any number of the targets
>   unchanged, even if those targets would be illegal. If the player
>   chooses to change some or all of the targets, the new targets must be
>   legal and must not cause any unchanged targets to become illegal.**
>
> 114.6e When changing targets or choosing new targets for a spell or ability, only the final set of targets is evaluated to determine
>   whether the change is legal. Example: Arc Trail is a sorcery that
>   reads "Arc Trail deals 2 damage to target creature or player and 1
>   damage to another target creature or player." The current targets of
>   Arc Trail are Runeclaw Bear and Llanowar Elves, in that order. You
>   cast Redirect, an instant that reads "You may choose new targets for
>   target spell," targeting Arc Trail. You can change the first target to
>   Llanowar Elves and change the second target to Runeclaw Bear.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your specific example is no. Since Into the Maw of Hell cannot target a player, you cannot redirect it onto a player. HOWEVER the answer to the general question is yes, you CAN redirect a spell from one type of target to another type, if the original spell can legally target that object.

Consider the card [Hero's Downfall](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHero%27s%5d%2b%5bDownfall%5d) which can target a creature or planeswalker. You can redirect that spell away from your planeswalker without needing to target another planeswalker, and instead target a creature.

If you choose to redirect, the new target(s) must be legal at the time you decide how to redirect. Neither player is allowed to make illegal choices. The one slight caveat there is you may redirect a counterspell onto the redirect itself, if it could counter an instant, since while redirect is resolving, it is still a spell on the stack. The countering spell immediately has an illegal target after redirect finishes resolving and is put into the graveyard.